# How do I keep alive a session on betfair in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I've wrote a nodejs app for betfair but my session id is expiring and I can't figure out how to write the keep alive code. Here is documentation for it: https://api.developer.betfair.com/services/webapps/docs/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Keep+Alive

Comment: Please share details about the error you receive and some code that you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. I converted the curl command on this site: http://curl.trillworks.com/#node.

This is my code:

```
var request = require('request');

var appkey = xxxx;
var ssid = xxxx;

function keepAlive() {
    var options = {
        url: 'https://identitysso.betfair.com/api/keepAlive',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'X-Application': appkey,
            'X-Authentication': ssid
        }
    };

    function callback(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
        }
    }

    request(options, callback);
}
```